# jquery focus on mobile field till reaches max length

Tags: jquery

I need to restrict the mobile number field, not loose its focus till it reaches the max length.

suppose, if i click on tab after entering some numbers, say for example, 3 numbers, It should not focus out.

I tried in the following way, but its working only the mobile number field is blank and also not able to enter any character in the field

### jquery

```
$(document).on('keydown','.mobile-verified', function(e){               
        if($('.mobile-verified').val().length>9 && e.which==9){
          //working code
        }
        else{            
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }       
    });
```

### template

```
<input name="mobilenum" 
 class="mobnum mobile-verified" 
 maxlength="10"  
 type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default tabbing behaviour only if the length of your input value is less than the `maxLength` property:

```
$(document).on('keydown','.mobile-verified', function(e){
    if (e.which == 9 && $(this).val().length < this.maxLength) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zs2u1571/1/)